# Interface for defining BNF and CNF formulas

Tags: gui-design, multi-selection, wizard

I'm developing a web app and need to make a web page that should allow my users to make [BNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) or [CNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) formulas like the following:

[image]

Some colleagues suggested that I make the page in this way:

[image]

Summarizing, I have to add a select component for each element inside the the formulas. I don't like this and I want some suggestions (or examples) from you about this.

Comment: I'm guessing a drag-and-drop for components, operations, etc onto a canvas of some sort is a better option.

Comment: @JimmyJunior Can you give me an example also through a picture?

Comment: Why not just let them key it is with & for intersection | for union and ! for not.  But don't ask what you call this (.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to us a syntax highlighting tool that supports your grammars such as the [extensible ace editor](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=higlighter).  This would guide the correct structure by flagging when BNF / CNF syntax is correct or not understood.

Extending this approach you can

- add special symbols as buttons above editor box (just like the ux.stackexchange UI)
- auto-prompt for symbols that are likely (see [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) behaviour)
- do real time validity parsing (on a per line basis)

Advantages of this UX include

1. rapid entry for experienced users
2. strong real-time guidance for less experienced users
3. supports learning different components of a language (e.g. operator, identifier, etc )
4. UI that looks like text as is presented in on-line/printed materials
5. Ability to cut & paste into UI